# what does lprm: Missing required attributes mean?

Tags: ubuntu, printing

My ubuntu 20.04 is printing the same single page web page every few minutes. I can't see how to stop it. I tried:

> lprm -

but after hanging for a while it returns

> lprm: Missing required attributes.

What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to clear the queue for your printer, instead of `lprm -` which results in an error, use the following command:

`cancel -a`